# How do I install msodbcsql17 driver for alpine linux?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, msodbcsql17

I found a [related issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/300) but it is under the msphpsql repo so I'm not sure if it applies to the driver in general for alpine. It says MS does not support yet.

[Official MS installation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) has installation instructions only for Debian, RedHat, SUSE, Ubuntu.

If there are any workarounds, please suggest.

If this is not possible, please elaborate your answer as technically as possible. I could not find a suitable answer for this question anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the `Dockerfile` I've tested.

```sh
FROM alpine

# Install dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add curl gnupg

# Download the desired package(s)
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk


# (Optional) Verify signature, if 'gpg' is missing install it using 'apk add gnupg':
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN gpg --verify mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk


# Install the package(s)
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
```

and this is the log I got,

```sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.174MB
Step 1/11 : FROM alpine
 ---> a24bb4013296
Step 2/11 : RUN apk --no-cache add curl gnupg
 ---> Running in d4f7b3b86157
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/32) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r4)
(2/32) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.41.0-r0)
(3/32) Installing libcurl (7.69.1-r0)
(4/32) Installing curl (7.69.1-r0)
(5/32) Installing libgpg-error (1.37-r0)
(6/32) Installing libassuan (2.5.3-r0)
(7/32) Installing libcap (2.27-r0)
(8/32) Installing libffi (3.3-r2)
(9/32) Installing libintl (0.20.2-r0)
(10/32) Installing libblkid (2.35.2-r0)
(11/32) Installing libmount (2.35.2-r0)
(12/32) Installing pcre (8.44-r0)
(13/32) Installing glib (2.64.4-r0)
(14/32) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20200523-r0)
(15/32) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20200523-r0)
(16/32) Installing libgcrypt (1.8.5-r0)
(17/32) Installing libsecret (0.20.3-r0)
(18/32) Installing pinentry (1.1.0-r2)
Executing pinentry-1.1.0-r2.post-install
(19/32) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r1)
(20/32) Installing gmp (6.2.0-r0)
(21/32) Installing nettle (3.5.1-r1)
(22/32) Installing p11-kit (0.23.20-r5)
(23/32) Installing libtasn1 (4.16.0-r1)
(24/32) Installing libunistring (0.9.10-r0)
(25/32) Installing gnutls (3.6.14-r0)
(26/32) Installing libksba (1.4.0-r0)
(27/32) Installing db (5.3.28-r1)
(28/32) Installing libsasl (2.1.27-r6)
(29/32) Installing libldap (2.4.50-r0)
(30/32) Installing npth (1.6-r0)
(31/32) Installing sqlite-libs (3.32.1-r0)
(32/32) Installing gnupg (2.2.20-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r16.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r4.trigger
OK: 27 MiB in 46 packages
Removing intermediate container d4f7b3b86157
 ---> f874be62c59e
Step 3/11 : RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
 ---> Running in 264bf790ce99
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  923k  100  923k    0     0  21.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21.9M
Removing intermediate container 264bf790ce99
 ---> cb999aaac06f
Step 4/11 : RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
 ---> Running in 7fe887056e7e
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  304k  100  304k    0     0  8236k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 8236k
Removing intermediate container 7fe887056e7e
 ---> 07885ffff557
Step 5/11 : RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig
 ---> Running in efb39bbe31a7
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   481  100   481    0     0  17178      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17178
Removing intermediate container efb39bbe31a7
 ---> 0b47b4bdc30d
Step 6/11 : RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig
 ---> Running in 08a264662da9
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   481  100   481    0     0  16033      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16033
Removing intermediate container 08a264662da9
 ---> dad9d122c7ae
Step 7/11 : RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
 ---> Running in ab82306e09cf
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0   1386      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1386
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key EB3E94ADBE1229CF: public key "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Removing intermediate container ab82306e09cf
 ---> 3a524358b99f
Step 8/11 : RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
 ---> Running in 0621d8db0ef8
gpg: Signature made Tue Jul  7 21:23:47 2020 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key EB3E94ADBE1229CF
gpg: Good signature from "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
Removing intermediate container 0621d8db0ef8
 ---> 5e4b528817f0
Step 9/11 : RUN gpg --verify mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
 ---> Running in 8a51c0d21e7e
gpg: Signature made Mon Jul  6 18:59:24 2020 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key EB3E94ADBE1229CF
gpg: Good signature from "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
Removing intermediate container 8a51c0d21e7e
 ---> a06ecc7c2031
Step 10/11 : RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
 ---> Running in 8f5c10bfb5ea
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/11) Installing krb5-conf (1.0-r2)
(2/11) Installing libcom_err (1.45.6-r0)
(3/11) Installing keyutils-libs (1.6.1-r1)
(4/11) Installing libverto (0.3.1-r1)
(5/11) Installing krb5-libs (1.18.2-r0)
(6/11) Installing libgcc (9.3.0-r2)
(7/11) Installing libstdc++ (9.3.0-r2)
(8/11) Installing openssl (1.1.1g-r0)
(9/11) Installing readline (8.0.4-r0)
(10/11) Installing unixodbc (2.3.7-r2)
(11/11) Installing msodbcsql17 (17.6.1.1)
Executing msodbcsql17-17.6.1.1.pre-install
Using this product constitutes agreement with the
End User License, which can be downloaded from
https://aka.ms/odbc17eula and found in
/usr/share/doc/msodbcsql17/LICENSE.txt .
If you do not agree with the terms, please uninstall
the product by typing 'apk del msodbcsql17'

Executing msodbcsql17-17.6.1.1.post-install
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r16.trigger
OK: 186 MiB in 57 packages
Removing intermediate container 8f5c10bfb5ea
 ---> 3e449c097c43
Step 11/11 : RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.apk
 ---> Running in 889ede754d73
(1/1) Installing mssql-tools (17.6.1.1)
Executing mssql-tools-17.6.1.1.pre-install
Using this product constitutes agreement with the
End User License, which can be downloaded from
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746949 and found in
/usr/share/doc/mssql-tools/LICENSE.txt .
If you do not agree with the terms, please uninstall
the product by typing 'apk del mssql-tools'

OK: 340 MiB in 58 packages
Removing intermediate container 889ede754d73
 ---> 0141e9b50f20
Successfully built 0141e9b50f20
Successfully tagged microsoft_odbc_17_alpine:latest
```

I hope this will solve you problem. You can find all the versions such as [Alpine Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#alpine17), [Debian](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#debian17), [Red Hat Enterprise Server and Oracle Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#redhat17), [SUSE Linux Enterprise Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#suse17) and [Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17) as well as you can also find [Previous versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-versions) installation details from [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) article.

Comment: This is nice. I think this got updated Jan/Feb 2020. Cool!! Now I just have to port everything in my production systems back to alpine ;)

Comment: @scientific_explorer it was updated 07/31/2020, few weeks ago. I faced the same issue and now everyone has a solution.